# SFDX Scratch Org Error: Invalid record ID

Tags: salesforcedx

I am following trailhead steps on setting up DX and encountered this error during creating my default scratch org. The command is:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias dreamhouse-org --setdefaultusername
```

and then I received this error:

> ERROR:  Invalid record ID. Specify valid record ID value.

I tried looking for a solution or details if anyone encountered the same error but haven't found one. Can you help me find out what I've missed? What does this error mean?

Comment: did you find anything about this yet ?